# RxJS Observable on Axios how to get access to the Response

Tags: rxjs, axios, observable, nestjs

I am working on getting a response from an HTTP POST in my NestJS project. I am using the `HttpModule` which wraps `Observables` from RxJS around Axios. here's some code:

```
async doSomething(bar: Bar) {

    const resp = await this.httpService
      .post(`${UPLOAD_URL}?app_token=111222333`, {
        foo: bar
      })
      .pipe(map(response => response))
      .toPromise()
      .catch(err => {
        this.logger.error(err)
      })

    this.logger.debug('response object')
    this.logger.debug(resp)
  }
```

In this particular case, I just want to see what the result of the `resp` object is. I'm getting a `Converting circular structure to JSON` error, though. So my question is, how would I view the response? I am okay with viewing it with the `.toPromise()` chain or without it. I'm not familiar with Observables so I convert it to a Promise. Not sure if that's a huge perf hit, but it isn't important for this question.

Comment: Use tap? The map is totally redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` you are using  is not helpful, as it does not actually do any mapping of the response. If you are wanting to log something in the observable without changing it you can use the `tap` operator and do something like

```
this.httpService().post(url, data).pipe(
  tap((data) => console.log(data),
).toPromise()
```

the reason you are getting the `Converting circular structure to JSON` error is because the Nest Logger will `JSON.stringify()` objects and does not use a circular replacer. Consider stringifying the object yourself with a circular replacer, using `console.log()` or using a different logging library.